# What is the best way write this long expression neatly?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, line-breaking

I currently have this equation

[image]

given by

```
\begin{document}

{\scriptsize

\begin{equation}

\omega_{\mp}^j=2\arctan\left(\frac{\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j \times \mathbf{z}_2^j\right) \mp \sqrt{\left[ \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1^j \times \mathbf{z}_2^j\right) \right]^2  + 2 \left[ \left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\times\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\right) \right]\left[\mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right)\right]- \left[\mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right) \right]^2  }}{2\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\times\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\right) - \mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right)} \right)

\end{equation}

}

\end{document}
```

It barely fits into one line using `\scriptsize`, and even then overflows slightly. What would be the neatest way to typeset this expression without using further substitutions such as `$\mathbf{z}_{12}^j = \left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)$`?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the expansion of the expression

[image]

with

[image]

Comment: There is a sign error in the denominator.

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you elaborate? I do not find anything wrong with the expression. Note that the entries of the second cross product where switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options, which consist mostly in adding a lot of negative horizontal spacing.

EDIT: Using Mico's suggestion, I changed the definition of `\stimes`, and added similar definitions for other symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\scdot}{{\cdot}}
\newcommand{\stimes}{{\times}}
\newcommand{\splus}{{+}}
\newcommand{\sminus}{{-}}
\newcommand{\smp}{{\mp}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
Shrinking a lot of horizontal spacing:
{\scriptsize
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mp}^j = 2\arctan\!\left(\! \frac{\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j \stimes \mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr) \smp \sqrt{\Bigl[ \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \scdot \bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j \stimes \mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]^2\! \splus 2 \Bigl[\! \bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr)\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]\!\Bigl[\mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr)\!\Bigr] \sminus \Bigl[\mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]^2 }}{2\bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr)\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\bigr) \sminus \mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr)} \right)
\end{equation}
}

Shrinking a lot of horizontal spacing, and splitting the numerator in two lines:
{\scriptsize
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mp}^j = 2\arctan\!\left( \frac{\splitfrac{
    \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j \stimes \mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr)
    }{
    \smp \sqrt{\Bigl[ \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \scdot \bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j \stimes \mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]^2\! \splus 2 \Bigl[\! \bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr)\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]\!\Bigl[\mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr)\!\Bigr] \sminus \Bigl[\mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr) \!\Bigr]^2}
}}{2\bigl(\mathbf{z}_1^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_2^j\bigr)\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\stimes\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\bigr) \sminus \mathbf{z}_2^j\scdot\bigl(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \mathbf{z}_3^j\bigr)} \right)
\end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a nice approach. Is there a way to also reduce the whitespace induced by the signs and brackets?

Comment: Of course, you could add ``\!``, which adds a negative spacing of 3/18 of ``\quad``, or any negative length with ``\hspace``.

Comment: Instead of `\newcommand{\stimes}{\hspace{-1.5pt}\times\hspace{-1pt}}`, do consider `\newcommand{\stimes}{{\times}}`.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mp}^j=2\arctan\left(\frac{A^j \mp 
\sqrt{\left( A^j \right)^2  + 2 B^jC^j-\left(C^j \right)^2}}{2B^j- C^j} \right)
\;,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 A^j&=\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j
    \times \mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\;,\\
 B^j&=\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\times\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\right)\;,\\
 C^j&=\mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right)\;.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would also use `\pm` instead of `\mp` and avoid `\mathbf`.

Comment: Thanks, but the expression I posted is actually the exactly the expansion of your equation. Usage of `\mp` follows from the derivation, and `\mathbf` is utilized as the variables are actually vectors. I would like to figure out a way to neatly format the expanded expression without further simplifications, as this is already included in the paper I'm writing on.

Comment: @Skydiver These are just my suggestions. As a reader I usually appreciate it if the equations get broken down in the way I propose. It is just a simple combination of three expressions (if I did not screw up). So you immediately see how things simplify if, say, `C^j` vanishes. You also see that you cannot afford to have `A^j` and `B^j` vanish (assuming you deal with real variables).

Comment: Yes I thought so, which is why I stated that I already have the compact form in my paper. For unrelated reasons it would have been really nice to have include the fully expanded version as well, but this is apparently not possible. Oh well, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to make the following suggestions:

- Get rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives. They're not needed in terms of making the equation more readable, but they do tend to insert a lot of horizontal whitespace.
- Omit the outermost pair of round parentheses (the pair around the fraction expression) entirely.
- Get rid of all 7 `\cdot` directives.

With these adjustments, you may change `\scriptsize` to `\small`. Your readers will appreciate you doing so...

Optionally, define `\newcommand\bz{\mathbf{z}}` in the preamble and replace all 23 [!] instances of `\mathbf{z}` in the equation with `\bz`. This doesn't affect the output, but it will certainly help de-clutter the input.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry} % set the page size parameters suitably
\newcommand\bz{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{document}

BEFORE
{\scriptsize
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mp}^j=2\arctan\left(\frac{\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j \times \mathbf{z}_2^j\right) \mp \sqrt{\left[ \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j \cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1^j \times \mathbf{z}_2^j\right) \right]^2  + 2 \left[ \left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\times\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\right) \right]\left[\mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right)\right]- \left[\mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right) \right]^2  }}{2\left(\mathbf{z}_1^j\times\mathbf{z}_2^j\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{1}^j\times\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j\right) - \mathbf{z}_2^j\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}^j-\mathbf{z}_3^j\right)} \right)
\end{equation}
}

\bigskip
AFTER
\bgroup
\small % <-- not "\scriptsize"
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mp}^j=2\arctan\frac{\bz_{\hat{3}}^j(\bz_1^j \times \bz_2^j) \mp 
\sqrt{[ \bz_{\hat{3}}^j  (\bz_1^j \times \bz_2^j) ]^2  
+ 2 [ (\bz_1^j\times\bz_2^j)(\bz_{1}^j\times\bz_{\hat{3}}^j) ]%
[\bz_2^j(\bz_{\hat{3}}^j-\bz_3^j)]
- [\bz_2^j(\bz_{\hat{3}}^j-\bz_3^j) ]^2  }}{%
2(\bz_1^j\times\bz_2^j)(\bz_{1}^j\times\bz_{\hat{3}}^j) 
- \bz_2^j(\bz_{\hat{3}}^j-\bz_3^j)} 
\end{equation}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be a decent solution. On a side note, is there a way to manually change the horizontal spacing induced by `\left`and `\right`?

Comment: @Skydiver - The answer to your question is yes. As (almost) always in TeX and LaTeX, there's more than one way to accomplish this goal. The simplest way I know of is to load the `mleftright` package and to issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble. For the equation at hand, though, you won't notice much of a difference as LaTeX has already "squeezed" the equation as much as possible. If, for some reason, you can't abandon the `\left` and `\right` sizing instructions, you may want to think about replacing all instances of `\times` with `{\times}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\scdot}{{\cdot}}
\newcommand{\stimes}{{\times}}
\newcommand{\splus}{{+}}
\newcommand{\sminus}{{-}}
\newcommand{\smp}{{\mp}}
\newcommand\bz{\mathbf{z}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document} 

With use of the \verb+nccmath+ for reducing equation size, new command \verb+\bz+ and removing \verb+\left(+ and \verb+\right)+ from @Mico answer, and reducing horisontal space around math operators and use of the \verb+\splitfrac+ from @Vincent answer for spliting square root into two lines and:
    \begin{equation}\medmath{
\omega_{\mp}^j = 2\arctan\!\left\lgroup 
    \frac{
    \bz_{\hat{3}}^j\scdot(\bz_1^j \stimes \bz_2^j) \smp 
%                   
    \sqrt{\splitfrac{\Bigl[\bz_{\hat{3}}^j \scdot (\bz_1^j \stimes \bz_2^j) \!\Bigr]^2\! \splus }
                    {2 \Bigl[ 
    (\bz_1^j\stimes\bz_2^j)\scdot (\bz_{1}^j\stimes\bz_{\hat{3}}^j ) \Bigr]\!\Bigl[\bz_2^j\scdot (\bz_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \bz_3^j ) \Bigr] \sminus \Bigl[\bz_2^j\scdot (\bz_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \bz_3^j ) \Bigr]^2}}
        }{2 (\bz_1^j\stimes\bz_2^j )\scdot (\bz_{1}^j\stimes\bz_{\hat{3}}^j ) \sminus \bz_2^j\scdot (\bz_{\hat{3}}^j \sminus \bz_3^j )} \right\rgroup
    }\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]